# 14.10 Live CD black screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-cd, 14.10, nouveau

First, the CD (64Bit) is alright, tried on another computer and is working.
Booting Live CD.

> - choose Language (OK)
> - Choose Keyboard-layout (OK)

When I go further, a black screen appears, with a cursor on the upper right corner.
The CD is reading further for a minute or two, but nothing on the screen

Tried with `nomodeset`, `acip=off` and `nolapic`, with same result.

Tried with `No splash` instead of `quit splash`. These are the last lines on my screen:

```
[6.970397] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Boot0:0x0c1080a1
```

With `nomodeset`:

```
[6.919661] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Boot0:0x0c1080a1  
[6.920729] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Chipset:GF108(NVC1)
```

With `nomodeset acpi=off nollapic`:

```
[6.907090] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Boot0:0x0c1080a1
[6.907174] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Chipset:GF108(NVC1)
[3.908179] nouveau [DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Family:NVC0
```

I had no troubles installing 14.04 months ago. (nor with earlier versions)

My system:

- Intel Core2
- Mem: 3 GB
- Video card: Nvidia Geforce GT430

I'm working in a resolution 1680x1050 on HDMI.

btw: all above happens also with the versions 14.10 of Xbuntu and Lubuntu too. Something changed between 14.04 and 14.10 so my video card is no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

On boot menu (grub2, where you choose between "Try Ubuntu without installing" and several other choices), select the option I just mentioned (Try without installing), but don’t press ENTER, instead press E.

In the following menu, search the line where you can find `quiet splash` and replace that with `nomodeset`.

It will boot to a console after some time where you should see lots of commands and text, until it stops and it is written something that looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu : []
```

You should be able to type. Enter the command `startx`.

After some waiting (the screen can be black but it is normal), it starts! The resolution is not maximum but that is *temporary* (your Ubuntu install will be normal).

Answer (score 0):

That worked, but the resolution was not workable.  I tried PClinuxOS (same problem with the latest DVD) and there an option to start in VESA.  That worked with a resolution of 1280 x 720.  So I searched how to start Ubuntu in VESA mode.
Gave the options `nomodeset` and `vga=normal`.  That was a workable resolution.
Installed Ubuntu and on the first restart in grub gave the same options.  It started, and got the resolution 1280 x 720.  Then I installed the Nvidia Legacy binary driver, did a reboot and got my normal desktop resolution back.

So this is a good workaround.  Thanks for putting me on the right direction.
I think the problem sits in the Nouveau driver, and after testing the problems (with my video card) started with the Ubuntu 14.04.1 version.

Comment: This may be better as a comment or edit to the other answer.